# Why do my normal maps look so terrible?

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I'm currently working on a model of a colonial era cannon. I'm wanting to add a normal map from a high poly model to the low poly model however whenever I try I always get some distorted results. So far I haven't figure out why I have looked all over the internet but so far haven't found any similar results. I made sure to add smoothing groups to my low poly model. I also tried the bake with and without a cage and had the same results. I feel like i'm missing a step but am not quite sure what that may be.

Here is a link the the image and blend files for what I have so far.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q99mj0bh4p2a5th/AABsyvPYcOh-TSfiT0qkbanTa?dl=0

Unfortunately I'm limited to two links per post so I can't post them directly here.

Comment: It's hard to say why those mixed hues appear on the borders however if looking at the UV map it's seen that they are around UV map, so this is the result of *Margin* setting (although afaik this still shouldn't happen). Anyway enable *Non-Color Data* for Image Texture node with normal map.